# Update on Parent Table with ado.net entity framework with domain services

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When I update a Employee I get an exception

> "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship."

My code receives an `Employee`, attaches to the context and save changes.

```
public void UpdateRAD_Tbl_OrderPatient(Employee emp)
{
    try
    {
        this.ObjectContext.RAD_Tbl_OrderPatient.AttachAsModified(emp);
        this.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
        this.ObjectContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

[image: fk]

The exception happens when a Foreign Key is changed on this object.

How can I attach the object changing this Foreign Key?

Comment: Here is might be some composite key issues.Are you sure the foreign key you are providing to Employee does really exist in Key???

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just attaching and saving, you could do a look up for the Key entity and add the Employee to Key.Employee and save the changes.